# How can I create an model that contains a list of models from query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to create an entity that contains a list of entities. Here is my code :

```
internal IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects(int customerId)
{
    string query = @"SELECT * 
                     FROM Project
                     INNER JOIN MediaAsset ON Project.CustomerId = MediaAsset.CustomerId
                     WHERE MediaAsset.CustomerId = @CustomerID";

    List<Project> projects = new List<Project>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customerId);

            using (varreader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    projects.Add(new Project
                    {
                        Assets = new List<MediaAsset>()//<--list of assets nested in Project
                        {
                              //right here.. how do i create the list of MediaAssets?
                        },
                        CustomerId = (int)reader["CustomerId"],
                        ProjectId = (int)reader["ProjectId"],
                        ProjectName = (string)reader["ProjectName"],
                        UserID = (int)reader["UserId"]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return projects;
}
```

Anyway to accomplish it this way? I have also been looking into Linq-to-SQL, but I already have a lot of methods, and I'd like to keep code consistent.

Comment: You should consider using Entity framework rather, reinventing the wheel isn't a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). You will be still using SQL statements, but you will gain automatic translation from the received data into entity objects.